# Store time in a Form to send to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I used to have my contact-form in php.

Now im converting everything to use ajax.
Here is the problem:

I used to have a function that checks the time the form was opened and the time the form was send. 
If the time-difference was too low the form would not be send.

i used `<?php echo time(); ?>` as the value of a hidden field.

Now with Jquery I am not able to use this value. It just reads the code.

I tried `<script>$.now()</script>` but it doesnt execute the code inside the value of the form.

So my question is:
How do i store the time a form was opened in a way that i can get it later via jquery?

Thanks for your help!

Addition:
FormerCode:

```
<div class="container col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Ihre Nachricht an uns</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                    <label for="adress"></label>
                <input type="text" class="adressform form-control" id="adress" name="adress" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" name="time" id="time"/>
                </div>    
            </div>
```

And i fetched it via:

```
$time = $_POST["time"];
```

Now im trying to get it via:

```
$(document).on('click','.formLink', function(){


    //Fetch the LinkValue 
    var linkValue = $(this).attr('value');
    var name     = $('#name').val();
    var email    = $('#email').val();
    var phone     = $('#phone').val();
    var message    = $('#message').val();
    var sendTime    = $.now();
    var endTime = $('#time').val();

// For testing only
    alert(sendTime + endTime);


});
```

Comment: Can you post the Javascript code you have tried?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid spam/bots?  Why not set up a honeypot field instead?  https://www.dexmedia.com/blog/honeypot-technique/

Comment: Generate a hidden form field with PHP and the time as the value?

Comment: I used both. Honeypot plus the timestamp-method.

Comment: To the general question of determining page load time with Javascript: just assign $.now() to a variable immediately after page load and keep that in the same scope as the click callback. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah right, but so far my problem has just been fixed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove PHP code from HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="time" id="time"/>
```

and then in JavaScript write:

```
var now = $.now();
$('#time').val(now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering.
Right after posting an answer in Jquery popped up which was similar. So i was able to use the answer.

If any other Beginner asks himself the same question: I used:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('time').value = $.now();
</script>
```

To set the value to the actual time!